# Why they said "deaf" instead of "deafs"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I was look through Cambridge Dictionary and I came across this sentence " the evening news has subtitles for the deaf" why they said "for deaf" instead of "for deafs"?

Comment: Fatima, I was looking through. Not I was look. "The deaf" means deaf people in English. The blind, the cripple, etc. for physical disabilities.

Comment: @Lambie - I think the term 'cripple' went out with 'PC' in the mid 80s, let alone in 'woke' of present day.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. But it explains the English.

Comment: … badly. It doesn't help someone new to the country who would be immediately shot down in flames for using the term

Comment: Also "the British" "the Chinese" but only certain nationalities are allowed, never "the Indian" or "the Canadian"

Comment: @DoneWithThis Politically correct in context is one thing, **description is another**: "Person with a physical disability Crippled, Lame, Deformed" https://askearn.org/page/people-first-language People First Language